# Why is my mortgage calculator showing incorrect decimal placement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, math, calculator

Im working on a calculator and so far so good except it is placing the decimal in the wrong place, thus causing my round function to give the incorrect number. The code and example can be seen below:

```js
$(function() {
  // Create USD currency formatter.
  var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'USD',
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  });

  function calculateAI() {
    var tax = parseFloat(('2,000').replace(/\$|,/g, ''));
    var hoa = parseFloat(('200').replace(/\$|,/g, ''));
    var cable = parseFloat(('30,000').replace(/\$|,/g, ''));
    var util = parseFloat(('44').replace(/\$|,/g, ''));
    var other = parseFloat(('0').replace(/\$|,/g, ''));
    var price = parseFloat(('200,000').replace(/\$|,/g, ''));
    var years = parseFloat(('30').replace(/\$|,/g, ''));
    var percent = parseFloat(('10').replace(/\$|,/g, ''));
    var yearp = parseFloat(('3.5').replace(/\$|,/g, ''));

    var deposit = (percent / 100) * price;
    var loan = price - deposit;
    var interest = (yearp / 100) / 12;
    var months = years * 12;

    var mtotal = loan * interest * (Math.pow(1 + interest, months)) / (Math.pow(1 + interest, months) - 1) || 0;
    var mortamount = mtotal;

    var ai_total = tax + hoa + cable + util + other + mortamount;

    document.getElementById('1870').innerHTML = formatter.format(ai_total);
    document.getElementById('1870-mort').innerHTML = mortamount;
  }
  calculateAI();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1870-mort"></div>
<div id="1870" style="margin-top: 3px;"></div>
```

The calculator is giving out --

```
808.2804380558849
```

But it's suppose to be --

```
80.82804380558849
```

So I can round it to "81" then continue with my calculations.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can click the `<>` and add the code here

Comment: Why do you think the answer should only be $81? https://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Mortgage-Payments shows the calculation for a 6% rate on $100,000 and it's $843. Your principle is about twice as much, but the rate is about half as much, so they should be in the same ballpark.

Comment: The reason why I said 81 is because I'm doing basically the same calculation on the single post page for that specific one and the answer there came out to 81 which was the same answer I got from another mortgage calculator.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not a JavaScript issue, but a problem with your formulas. So you should add some context for those: what is it you want to calculate, where did you get the formulas from, or what were your thoughts divising them yourself? But in that case this is no longer a programming problem, so better ask those questions elsewhere. The part where you seem to calculate a monthly interest by simply dividing the annual interest seems highly suspicious to me. Better do all the computation in years, and treat a month as 1/12 of a year in the Math.pow invocation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out, it was an typo in my code on the post page the made the numbers different. My formula in fact does work as it should. Even though my question was because an error on my part, hopefully people can find the code I posted useful.

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: @Marimba one of the values was 20,000 when it was suppose to be 200,000, and that's because I didnt set the input fields value to be dynamic and had left the set value I was using for testing.

Answer (score 4):

Some console logging has been added in the snippet below. This outputs the following:

```
tax = 2000, hoa = 200, cable = 30000, util = 44, other = 0, price = 200000, years = 30,
       percent = 10, yearp = 3.5, loan = 180000, deposit = 20000, months = 360, 
       interest = 0.002916666666666667
mtotal = loan * interest * (Math.pow(1 + interest, months))
                         / (Math.pow(1 + interest, months) - 1)
       = 180000 * 0.002916666666666667 * (1.0029166666666667 ^ 360)
                                       / ((1.0029166666666667 ^ 360) - 1)
       = 180000 * 0.002916666666666667 * 2.853287165195746
                                       / 1.8532871651957459
       = 808.2804380558849
```

Plugging the same numbers into https://www.desmos.com/scientific gives the same result. There doesn't seem to be anything obvious wrong in the Javascript here (e.g. due to rounding errors, number parsing, type conversion etc.) so my suspicion would be the formula itself.

```js
$(function() {
  // Create USD currency formatter.
  var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'USD',
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  });

  function calculateAI() {
    var tax = parseFloat(('2,000').replace(/\$|,/g, ''));
    var hoa = parseFloat(('200').replace(/\$|,/g, ''));
    var cable = parseFloat(('30,000').replace(/\$|,/g, ''));
    var util = parseFloat(('44').replace(/\$|,/g, ''));
    var other = parseFloat(('0').replace(/\$|,/g, ''));
    var price = parseFloat(('200,000').replace(/\$|,/g, ''));
    var years = parseFloat(('30').replace(/\$|,/g, ''));
    var percent = parseFloat(('10').replace(/\$|,/g, ''));
    var yearp = parseFloat(('3.5').replace(/\$|,/g, ''));
    var deposit = (percent / 100) * price;
    var loan = price - deposit;
    var interest = (yearp / 100) / 12;
    var months = years * 12;

    var mtotal = loan * interest * (Math.pow(1 + interest, months)) / (Math.pow(1 + interest, months) - 1) || 0;
    console.log('tax = ' + tax + ', hoa = ' + hoa + ', cable = ' + cable + ', util = ' + util + ', other = ' + other + ', price = ' + price + ', years = ' + years + ', percent = ' + percent + ', yearp = ' + yearp + ', loan = ' + loan + ', deposit = ' + deposit + ', months = ' + months + ', interest = ' + interest
       + '\n' + 'mtotal = loan * interest * (Math.pow(1 + interest, months)) / (Math.pow(1 + interest, months) - 1)'
       + '\n' + '       = ' + loan + ' * ' + interest + ' * (' + (1 + interest) + ' ^ ' + months + ') / ((' + (1 + interest) + ' ^ ' + months + ') - 1)'
       + '\n' + '       = ' + loan + ' * ' + interest + ' * ' + (Math.pow(1 + interest, months)) + ' / ' + (Math.pow(1 + interest, months) - 1)
       + '\n' + '       = ' + mtotal);

    var mortamount = mtotal;
    var ai_total = tax + hoa + cable + util + other + mortamount;
  }
  calculateAI();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1870-mort"></div>
<div id="1870" style="margin-top: 3px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets do a quick sanity check. We have a loan of 180,000 to be paid back monthly over a period of 30 years or (360 months). Ignore any interest accumulation the very minimum monthly payment would be

```
180,000 / 360 = 500
```

This gives a strong indication that the $808.28 monthly figure is in the correct ball park and the $80.82 figure cannot ever be enough to pay back the loan.